# How to populate a dropdownlist based on the selection made in another dropdownlist?

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

How do I automatically populate the second dropdown based on the selection made in the first one. Say if I choose a contry in the first dropdown, then I want to display a list of cities from that country in the second dropdown. Is there a way to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use AJAX

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    var optionId = $(this).val();
    $.post('ajax/getData.php',
           {id: optionId}, 
           function(data) {
              $("#div2").html(data);
           }, 
           "json"
    );
});
```

Here is example HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <select id="select1">
        <option value="1">aaaaa</option>
        ....
    </select>
</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
```

Comment: Thnx, but I'm not using PHP for this project. I there a way I can place the value of say #div2 anywhere?

Comment: @prodac , you can use a hidden variable or jquery' .data to store a value for div http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/